# Is that possible to apply method level security for Spring @MVC controllers?

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have applied below code, but it was not working, can any one please give me some solution for this.Thanks.

**Controller method:**

```
@Controller
public class UserController {
@Secured("ROLE_USER")
@RequestMapping(value="user/{userName}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody User getAvailability(@PathVariable String userName, HttpServletResponse response) { }
}
```

**applicationContext-security.xml related configurations:**

```
    <global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled" />

    <http>
        <intercept-url pattern="/user" requires-channel="https"/>
        <http-basic/>
    </http>

    <authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <authentication-provider>
            <user-service>
                <user password="password" name="manager" authorities="ROLE_MANAGER"/>
                <user password="password" name="user" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            </user-service>
        </authentication-provider>
    </authentication-manager>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to apply the security using the `<intercept_url>` tag.

For example:

```
    <intercept-url pattern="/user" requires-channel="https" access="ROLE_USER"/>
```

Comment: Hi ericacm! many thanks for your reply, yes over the time I have done that way, but now (with newer Spring Security) it seems we can do that same access contorting stuffs, on method level know, that mean rather than doing any xml configuration, directly we can denote that for particular method.

Answer (score 0):

If you would want to use url based access control you need to add the /**

```
<intercept-url pattern="/user/**" requires-channel="https"/>
```

If you want method level security then you need

```
<context:component-scan base-package="com.yourcompany.etc"/>

<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/>
```

also in your web.xml you need to add the spring security config as a parameter to your servlet

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>myservlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>WEB-INF/applicationContext-security.xml</param-value>
    </init-param>
    <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

Comment: Hi Peter Szanto! Many thanks for your answer, with those configurations, @Secured will not works inside the Spring Controller (with @Controller).

Comment: It does work on controllers too, but you need to add the spring security related XML to the xml of your servlet. At least the     <security:global-method-security secured-annotations="enabled"/> should be there

Comment: Hi Peter Szanto! Thanks a lot for freed back. I will try that, Thanks.